# How do I URL Rewrite for below situation?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web page at following url.

https://example.com/contact.php

Now I want to configure the URL redirect like. If user open page with complete URL, it should remove .php from URL automatically.

https://example.com/contact.php  ==> 
https://example.com/contact/

Now the https://example.com/contact/ URL should load content from /contact.php.  I am trying below .htaccess but it failed with a redirect loop.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php  [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^contact.php$
RewriteRule ^contact.php$ http://example.com/contact/  [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code for remove the extention

```
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(one)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This removes .php extensions from all php files while the OP asked about removing .php from a specific file.

Comment: i have edited the code this will remove from the one.php to one lets have a look

Comment: This still redirects `/anyfile.php` to `/anyfile` . You did not update the `RewriteCond` .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# It redirects the contact.php to /contact/, so .php extension is removed
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /contact/ [L,R=301]

# It fetches contact.php when /contact/ is requested by the user
RewriteRule ^/contact/$ /contact.php [L,NC]
```